# Devexpress WPF GridControl server side filtering

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, filter, devexpress, server-side

I'm trying DevExpress Universe 2011 1.6 and using Entity Framework and WPF to develop an application.

I have a simple requirement but really can't continue without it. I need some kind of mix between client and server mode for filling my GridControl's ItemsSource.

I have database tables with hundreds of thousands rows, which I can't bring in each query because of memory consumption issues. So I need to do filtering on server side (like server mode does). My problem with server mode is that I also can't access the database for each scrolling, because of network performance issues.

I thought that, if server mode lets you do filtering and grouping on the database, there should definitely be a way to do it without paging support. Unfortunately I couldn't find it myself.

Any suggestions will be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This pertains to version 9.1.4, so it might be slightly out of date, but you can turn off the vertical scrollbar in the DXGrid for WPF following the solution described [here](http://devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q207271.aspx).  That is

```
<dxg:GridControl.Resources>
<ControlTemplate x:Key="{dxg:GridColumnViewThemeKey ResourceKey=ControlTemplate}">
    <dxg:GridViewScrollViewer x:Name="scr" 
  CanContentScroll="true" 
  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" 
  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
  Focusable="False"
  Template="{DynamicResource {dxg:GridColumnViewThemeKey ResourceKey=ScrollViewerTemplate}}">
    </dxg:GridViewScrollViewer>
</ControlTemplate>
```